# schedule_task() argument after * must be an iterable, not int

Tags: django, django-views, celery

Here I am using `apply_async` method with `countdown` and `expires` arguments to execute the task after some countdown and expires the task at certain datetime.

But I got this error

```
Django Version: 3.0.6 
Exception Type: TypeError
 Exception Value:    schedule_task() argument after * must be an iterable, not int
```

How to solve this error ?

tasks

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute=1), ignore_result=False)  
def schedule_task(pk):

    task = Task.objects.get(pk=pk)
    unique_id = str(uuid4())
```

views

```
form = CreateTaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            unique_id = str(uuid4())
            obj = form.save(commit=False)           
            obj.created_by = request.user
            obj.unique_id = unique_id
            obj.status = 0
            obj.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            # schedule_task.delay(obj.pk)
            schedule_task.apply_async((obj.pk),expires=datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5), countdown=int(obj.search_frequency))

            return redirect('crawler:task-list')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe that helps you out. For further info check https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html#id2

```
schedule_task.apply_async(expires=datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5), countdown=int(obj.search_frequency),kwargs={"pk":obj.pk})
```

Comment: Solved the answer.Thanks. I have one further question.Here i am setting `run_every=crontab(minute=1)`  to run the task but  I want to change the minute with `task.search_frequency` value. Is it possible?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve here. But from what i understand it feels like you want to reschedule periodic tasks based upon  some user input. If that is the case have a look at this repo. It's a django app that does exactly that. Here is the link https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat